# How to simulate human keyboard input of a long text using Python?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I would like to simulate typing of huge text. I've tried to use pyautogui to do that, but I't didn't worked properly since the computer was not detecting the keys being pressed:

```
pyautogui.typewrite('I love python! It is such an amazing language.')
```

I couldn't think of another way to do that than using pynput.keyboard library, but as I have a huge text, that would not be a viable option. I don't know if there is a way to simulate the keys other than create a line for each letter.

```
keyboard = Controller()

keyboard.press('I')
keyboard.release('I')

keyboard.press('L')
keyboard.release('L')

keyboard.press('O')
keyboard.release('O')

keyboard.press('V')
keyboard.release('V')
```

Is there a way to simulate keys being pressed to write a text without having to create a single line for each letter that the script would have to type?

Comment: Do you mean that `keyboard.press` and `keyboard.release` do what you want? Why don't you use those in a loop?

Comment: This appears to be a software testing question, "how do I present lots of interactive input to an app to verify correctness / performance / resource consumption?" https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Please tell us about the app, and your testing concerns. Is it a web app, for which Selenium might be a good fit? Does the app accept keystrokes via a pty, so Expect might work? For what you literally asked, surely you could do `for ch in 'big text': keyboard.press(ch); keyboard.release(ch)`, no? Perhaps with a moment of sleep before the release?

Comment: Do you know that pynput.keyboard.Controller() comes with the `.type()` method?

Comment: @mkrieger1 to be honest with you, I don't know how to make a loop using press and release. I'm still learning the basics of python.

Comment: @J_H thanks for the tip! I will try to do that.

Comment: @Claudio didn't know about that, will definitely try!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below demonstrates that there is a way to simulate keys being pressed to write a text without having to create a single line for each letter that the script would have to type.

In addition to that the provided solution allows to execute code placed in the same script after the code for automated typing which feature is used to show the automated keyboard input in a typing speed test GUI:

```
import pynput
import random 
import threading
import time

txt = "pynput is typing like a human"
#txt = "abc" 

class Sim_keyb_typing(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, text, 
                 strt_delay=1.5, 
                 dct_delays={('a','i'):0.15}, 
                 delayrange=(0.1, 0.3) ):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

        self.text       = text
        self.strt_delay = strt_delay
        self.last_char  = " "
        self.dct_delays = dct_delays
        self.delayrange = delayrange

        self.ppkbC = pynput.keyboard.Controller()

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(self.strt_delay)
        for char in self.text:
            delay = self.dct_delays.get( 
                (self.last_char, char), random.uniform(*self.delayrange) )
            time.sleep(delay)
            self.ppkbC.type(char)
            self.last_char = char

# Let's wait 1.5 seconds and then start typing: 
skt = Sim_keyb_typing(txt)
skt.start()
# Wait for Sim_keyb_typing(txt) to finish
#skt.join()

# ======================================================================
import tkinter
import time
import threading
import random
import string

class simpleTypeSpeedGUI: # creates tkinter GUI mainloop

    def __init__(self, txt):
        self.root = tkinter.Tk()
        self.root.title("Type Speed Test (starts on first keypress)")
        self.root.geometry("1600x400")

        self.text_lines = txt.split("\n")
        self.text_line = random.choice(self.text_lines)
        self.len_text_line = len(self.text_line)

        # Label showing text to type:
        self.sample_label = tkinter.Label(self.root, text=self.text_line, font=("Helvetica", 14))
        self.sample_label.grid( row=0, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=15, pady=15, sticky='w')

        # Text box receiving typing input: 
        self.input_textbox = tkinter.Entry(self.root, width=120, font=("Helvetica", 14))
        self.input_textbox.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=15, pady=15)
        # Registering callback function for text box keyboard input keypress
        self.input_textbox.bind("<KeyRelease>", self.on_key_up) 
        # The reason for          KeyRelease  is to have updated widget content in the callback function
        self.input_textbox.focus()

        # Label showing typing speed: 
        self.speed_label = tkinter.Label(self.root, text="Typing speed: \n---- \n---- \n---- \n---- ", font=("Helvetica", 12))
        self.speed_label.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=10)

        # Button for restart/reset of typing: 
        self.reset_button = tkinter.Button(self.root, text="Reset", command=self.reset, font=("Helvetica", 18))
        self.reset_button.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=15, pady=15)

        # Standard value for average number of characters in a word 
        self.std_char_per_word = 5
        # used to calculate words per minute from typing speed in chars/min

        # initialisation of code flow control values: 
        self.start_time     = None
        self.end_time       = None
        self.printable = string.printable[:-5]

        self.root.mainloop()

    def on_key_up(self, event):
        # processing on key release because on key press results
        # in the widget content are not yet updated with the key char. 
        if event.keycode == 9: # pressed Escape => EXIT
            print("\nEscape-EXIT")
            self.root.destroy()
            return # <- required because root.destroy() doesn't block 
                   # execution of further code which then runs into 
                   # trouble as .destroy() makes widgets not available

        if self.start_time is None:
            self.start_time = time.perf_counter()

        input_textbox = self.input_textbox.get()
       
        # print(f'{event.keycode=} => "{event.char=}" ')

        if input_textbox == self.text_line:
            self.running = False
            self.input_textbox.config(fg="green")
            self.end_time = time.perf_counter()
        else: 
            if self.text_line.startswith(input_textbox):
                self.input_textbox.config(fg="black")
            else:
                self.input_textbox.config(fg="red")

        self.show_typespeed()

    def show_typespeed(self):
        curr_time = time.perf_counter()
            
        if   self.start_time is not None and self.end_time is not None:  
            time_diff = self.end_time - self.start_time
        elif self.start_time is not None and self.end_time is None: # and self.end_time is None  
            time_diff = curr_time - self.start_time
        elif self.start_time is None and self.end_time is None: 
            self.speed_label.config(text="Speed: \n---- CPS\n---- CPM\n---- WPS\n---- WPS")
            return
        cps = self.len_text_line / time_diff
        cpm = cps * 60.0
        wps = cps / self.std_char_per_word
        wpm = wps * 60.0
        self.speed_label.config(text=f"Speed: \n{cps:5.2f} CPS\n{cpm:5.2f} CPM\n{wps:5.2f} WPS\n{wpm:5.2f} WPM")

    def reset(self):
        self.start_time = None
        self.end_time   = None
        self.text_line = random.choice(self.text_lines)
        self.len_text_line = len(self.text_line)
        self.sample_label.config(text=self.text_line)
        self.input_textbox.delete(0, tkinter.END)
        self.show_typespeed()

sTSG = simpleTypeSpeedGUI(txt)
```

Comment: my friend, you nailed it! I still don't know much about the concept of classes, but I will look further into that. Your code in fact makes the computer thinks that there is a human typing on the keyboard.

Comment: What exactly was the problem with `pyautogui` you have solved using `pynput`? Did you use `pyautogui.typewrite()`?

Comment: the computer was not detecting pyautogui as a human typing, so I would have none tracking of the keyboard usage

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use the python `keyboard` module.

```
import keyboard as kbd # importing keyboard module
import time
string = "I love python! It is such an amazing language."
time.sleep(3) # 3 second gap to avoid unwanted actions
kbd.write(string, 0.1) # 0.1 second typewrite effect
```

You can omit lines `2` and `4`. I just added that for testing purposes to keep a delay before running the code.

Comment: `0.1` gives 600 strokes/minute ... it's extremely fast ... to be realistic `0.2` would be already fast typing and `0.15` the practically lowest value to simulate common human keyboard input. A first step estimation would be in my opinion random values spread over the range of  `0.1 - 0.3` or `0.15 - 0.45`, but this would need a loop for key-presses of single characters.

Comment: I think that's alright. They could play with the numbers based on their wish.

Comment: your code works, but my software still detect as a machine typing so none key pressing was detected. Looping keyboard.press(ch) as @J_H suggested worked though.

Comment: When did you mention you want the `software` to detect key presses? That's a totally different approach.